# Using grep to get muliple words between ' ' and manipulate them

Tags: python, bash, grep

It is been a while since last time I used grep and I could use some help.

Here is what I am trying to do. For an out as the following:

```
('Predicted:', [(u'n02504458', u'African_elephant', 0.99588591), (u'n01871265', u'tusker', 0.004068926), (u'n02504013', u'Indian_elephant', 4.499541e-05)])
```

I would like to grep the three variables n02504458, African_elephant, and  0.99588591. I would also like to store 0.99588591 as double to check the value and somehow edit a python script to include n02504458.

I know this seems like a lot but any help is most appreciated.

Comment: This is python code !

Comment: Bash is **really** the wrong tool for this. Python will be able to parse this data natively -- see `ast.literal_eval()` in the standard library to do so safely.

Comment: ...so, don't automate editing your Python script; instead, write your Python script to read the data it needs itself.

Comment: This is an output of a python code

Comment: And so it should be easier to adjust the code to output exactly what you need, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Jan  5 2018, 10:41:29) 
[GCC 7.2.1 20171224] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = ('Predicted:', [(u'n02504458', u'African_elephant', 0.99588591), (u'n01871265', u'tusker', 0.004068926), (u'n02504013', u'Indian_elephant', 4.499541e-05)])
>>> print(x[1][0])
(u'n02504458', u'African_elephant', 0.99588591)
```

Edit :

```
>>> print(x[1][0][2])
0.99588591
```

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: How would you separate the rest? How can you use n02504458 as string variable for another function? Also, how would you be able to store 0.99588591 as a double?

Comment: The issue is that the output comes from the following command and I cannot simply have a print within print:

    print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0])

Answer (score 0):

I think I just figured out. Here is what I did to get the first argument and the third argument.

For the first argument:

```
print(decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0][0][0])
```

For the third argument:

```
print(decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0][0][2])
```

I would however like to have both printed without having to call `decode_predictions(preds, top=3)` function twice. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why call it twice? `result = decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0][0]` on one line, and then you can refer to both `result[0]` and `result[2]` in the same statement, pass each as a separate argument, or do whatever else you need to.

Comment: Oh great. Thanks.